# Is there any manifold that is not a subspace of a finite dimensional euclidean space?

Tags: manifolds

I mean, is there any topological space that is locally euclidean, Haudorff and second countable and can't be embedded into a finite dimensional Euclidean space. 
I think it's hard for me to find such spaces because manifolds are often described visually as an euclidean subspace..

Comment: No, there is no. This is the 'embedding thm' for manifolds.

Comment: I'm not sure, but someone says that it's a special case, when the space is 'riemannian'..

Answer (score 6):

Actually, "manifold" is not required.  A theorem of Karl Menger*

> A separable metric space that has dimension $n$  (in the sense of topological dimension) may be embedded in Euclidean space of dimension at most $2n+1$.

*Or, you may prefer to say: stated by Menger, then proved by S. Lefschetz (1931) and independently by G. Nöbeling (1930).